# jQuery Bounce In Place

Tags: jquery, html, css, inline, bounce

I need my list item elements to bounce in place and not fall all over each other.

I created a JSFiddle of what I mean: http://jsfiddle.net/RGvjj/

Can someone advise me as to why the elements are doing that and what I need to do to fix that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try removing the `inline` display from the `<li>` and use `float:left` instead.

**Try it out:** http://jsfiddle.net/RGvjj/1/

```
#navigation li {
    font-size: 20px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    border-left: 3px solid #1161A5;
    color: #ffffdd;
    text-decoration: none;
    float:left;
}
```

---

**EDIT:** To explain, I'm guessing this is happening because when you animate an element, jQuery changes the `display` to `block`. So you were ending up with a `block` element (the `<a>`) inside an `inline` element (the `<li>`) which doesn't work.

By using `float:left`, the `<li>` retains its `block` display, which makes it valid for the `<a>` to be `block`.

Comment: I had a similar problem; changing it to display:inline-block helped.